# Animated TV show from the early 2000s, possibly late 90s. Involved magic and collecting gems. Ended with live magic trick

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

All I can remember is that it had some kind of Asian origin, probably Japanese, and that it always ended with a live (not animated) performance of a magic trick / illusion. I think it was a woman and possibly a man doing these tricks, and I have a feeling that they were supposed to be the live version of the show's characters.

Although, I can't remember if that was actually part of the show or just something that the Australian tv channel added afterwards. The only thing that I remember about the show is that they went on adventures to collect gems or possibly crystals that were diamond shaped, from memory. I can remember one episode where they collected a gem from underwater. And I believe these gems were inserted into some kind of wand or device or into something and then it did something special like giving them magic powers or possibly summoning something maybe?

I remember thinking it was a really good show but it didn't go for very long. As in, not many seasons. I was sad when it ended. I'm pretty confident that it isn't *Deltora Quest*.